# Get all WMS layer features from the Openlayers 3 with in selected bounding box?

Tags: openlayers-3, geoserver, wms

For vector layer we have solution to get the feature with in the bounding box.

PFB the solution

http://tsauerwein.github.io/ol3/animation-flights/examples/box-selection.html

but, Is there any respective solution for for WMS layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any respective solution for for WMS layer?

No from my knowledge.
It seems confirmed from this topic ["Use GetFeatureInfo with OpenLayers and a Bounding Polygon"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72358/use-getfeatureinfo-with-openlayers-and-a-bounding-polygon) on GIS.stackexchange forum and from reading the official GeoServer [WMS GetFeatureInfo documentation section](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo)

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Gratier for the quick replay and confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Some partial solution :

Using  WFS service we can able to pass polygon geometry and get feature from geo-server.